# Javascript widget appearing only for logged in users

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript widget, but the widget should only be seen by logged in users.

```
<script>
    window.fwSettings={
    'widget_id':77000003788
    };
    !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://euc-widget.freshworks.com/widgets/77000003788.js' async defer></script>
```

I have tried to use a php function, but it didnt work:

```
<?php

if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo '<script>
    window.fwSettings={
    'widget_id':77000003788
    };
    !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://euc-widget.freshworks.com/widgets/77000003788.js' async defer></script>';
}

?>
```

I placed the code in my footer.php file right before the body-closing tag as the widget should be placed there.

Any help is appreciated! (and yes, I'm very new to coding)

Comment: Please explain "it didnt work". Does it _not_ show for anyone? Or is it showing for everyone?

Comment: it doesnt show anything including the footer (theres no error warning in the console though)

Comment: how do you determinne a user is "logged in"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a quoting problem. You are starting a string with a single quote, `'`, but then you including additional single quotes inside the string. Make sure to turn on both WordPress and PHP error reporting when debugging, it will warn you about this. The easiest solution is to break out of PHP and switch back to HTML mode.

```php
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()): ?>
<script>
    window.fwSettings={
    'widget_id':77000003788
    };
    !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://euc-widget.freshworks.com/widgets/77000003788.js' async defer></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```